# Firefox Australis status bar not showing

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, user-interface

Just restarted my Firefox and voila... "Australis" is installed (never clicked "yes I want this"), but oh well, get on with the progress, right? I am fine with progress, but there is no status bar anymore! Seriously, how else are users supposed to preview the link and where it leads to?

Somewhere on the Firefox site it says that link preview will show when required. I don't see it. Am I doing something wrong?

Here is a picture showing Chrome and Firefox, when the mouse is hovering over the <kbd>**Questions**</kbd> link at the top (yes, the window has focus)

[image]

I have already tried to

- Right click Toolbar
- Select Customize...
- Click <kbd>Restore Defaults</kbd>

Comment: If you mouse over a link you should see the link in the bottom left corner. Is that not showing up?

Comment: @AlexMcKenzie nope...

Comment: I have Firefox `29.0` but I still get link previews as usual. Start Firefox in [Safe Mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode) to see whether you still get the same issue. Also, try using a [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable).

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised you only noticed now, the status bar actually went away in Firefox 4. So link target was being shown in an overlay in the bottom-left corner for quite a while already - see screenshot below. What you probably meant by "status bar" was actually the add-on bar - a rather awkward solution that allowed extensions to dump their icons somewhere. The add-on bar was optional and hidden by default, it was never showing the link target. But maybe you installed some add-on to move link target display into the add-on bar. If you did then that same add-on likely prevents the link target from displaying now.

[image: Link target display in Firefox]

Comment: Yes, I did have some extensions that made the "status bar" permanent. They don't work with the new version. The part that you indicated with an arrow is what I am expecting to see now (without extensions), referred to as "link preview" in my OP, but it's not there. Hence the question.

Comment: I've added pictures to show what I am missing @Wladimir